# Are relatable worlds and peoples mentioned in scripture?

Tags: scripture

Are there other worlds with relatable peoples described in scripture?

By relatable,

- the people should be mortal
- the people should have free will for good and bad, and can allow themselves to be happy or sad
- the world should be accessible by a very fast rocket from Earth, not in another universe